# Can you use someone's google play account for Firebase Auth with Google login?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play

I have tried to Google it but I could not find it anywhere.

Every android phone has a google play store account which allows you access to the play store. I'm making an app that uses Firebase Auth for authentication, and you authenticate with Google Sign-In. Is the Google Play account useable for authentication? Or is a new email required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the Google Play account useable for authentication?

Yes, any of your Google accounts that are present on your device can be used to authenticate with Firebase.

> Or is a new email required?

No, there is no need for a new account/email address in order to use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's great to hear! This question can be closed and I have accepted your answer :)